# Custom sort for custom render cell Data Grid Material UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [Material UI V4 Data Grid](https://v4.mui.com/components/data-grid/#data-grid) component in a React Js app.

The `Data Grid` component has required `rows` (`list` type) and `columns` (`list` type) props.

Here is a sample of a row item:

```js
const rows = [
  {
    id: 1,
    customerName: "Silvestr Irma",
    carModel: {
      name: "Centurion",
      color: "red"
    },
    location: {
      name: "Belgium",
      address: "avenue Verheyen 93"
    }
  },
];
```

and here is a sample of the column list:

```js
const columns = [
    {
      field: "customerName",
      headerName: "Custom Name",
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 200
    },
    {
      field: "carModel",
      headerName: "Car Model",
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 200,
      renderCell: (params) => (
        <Typography variant="subtitle2" className={classes.bolderText}>
          {params.value.name}
        </Typography>
      )
    },
    {
      field: "location",
      headerName: "Location",
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 300,
      renderCell: (params) => (
        <div>
          <Typography variant="subtitle2" className={classes.bolderText}>
            {params.value.name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="subtitle2" className={classes.ligtherText}>
            {params.value.address}
          </Typography>
        </div>
      )
    }
  ];
```

If we sort the `Data Grid` component based on the customer name column, the sort works fine for both ascendant and descendant as we can see in the images below:

[image]

[image]

However, the sort doesn't work fine for columns that have `render cell` field (car model and location columns) as you can see in the images below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**So how I implement custom sort for columns that have `render cell` field?**
For example the car model name column (Centurion, Centaur, and Buffalo) and the location name column (Belgium, Germany, and Spain).

Here is the full code https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-custom-sort-data-grid-material-ui-dp609

Comment: Thank you for providing an example to work from -- that makes life SO much easier when trying to help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you've probably guessed, with the `renderCell`, you'll need to create a custom function ([`sortComparator`](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-custom-sort-data-grid-material-ui-forked-2kw12?file=/src/App.jsx:416-1248)) so the DataGrid knows how to sort the columns.  In your case, this sort might suffice:

```
    {
      field: "location",
      headerName: "Location",
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 300,
      renderCell: (params) => (
        <div>
          <Typography variant="subtitle2" className={classes.bolderText}>
            {params.value.name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="subtitle2" className={classes.ligtherText}>
            {params.value.address}
          </Typography>
        </div>
      ),
      sortComparator: (v1, v2) => v1.name.localeCompare(v2.name)
    }
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-custom-sort-data-grid-material-ui-forked-2kw12?file=/src/App.jsx:416-1248

Comment: you're right, I've read and tried the `sortComparator` field documentation but I didn't get it right. your answer helps a lot. thank you so much